# Merging fields in a Mongo Document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection called `Cars` which has documents in the following format:

`{
  "_id": "100066114",
  "cars": [{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a9fed0218071f56ba7eca48"),
    "customer_name": "ABC",
    "otherdetails":"some details"
  }, {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a9fed0218071f56ba7eca4a"),
    "customer_name": "",
    "otherdetails":"some other details"
  }, {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a9fed0218071f56ba7eca49"),
    "customer_name": "",
    "otherdetails":"some more details"
    }, {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a9fed0218071f56ba7eca47"),
    "customer_name": "ABC",
    "otherdetails":"details"
     }]
}`

I would like to change this document to the following format:

`{
  "_id": "100066114",
  "customer_name":"ABC"
  "cars": [{
    "_id": ObjectId("5a9fed0218071f56ba7eca48"),
    "otherdetails":"some details"
  }, {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a9fed0218071f56ba7eca4a"),
    "otherdetails":"some other details"
  }, {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a9fed0218071f56ba7eca49"),
    "otherdetails":"some more details"
    }, {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a9fed0218071f56ba7eca47"),
    "otherdetails":"details"
     }]
}`

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `customer_name` should be evaluated as a first non-empty value from cars

```
  db.Cars.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      customer_name: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          { $filter: { input: { $map: { input: "$cars", as: "car", in: "$$car.customer_name" } }, 
            as: "customer_name", cond: {$ne: ["$$customer_name", ""]} } }          
        ,0]
      },
      cars: {
        $map: {
          input: "$cars",
          as: "car",
          in: { _id: "$$car._id", otherdetails: "$$car.details" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

So to get the cars array you just need to use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to specify which properties should be transferred to the output. To evaluate `customer_name` you should take `customer_name` from each car (using [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)) filter out empty strings (using [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)) and take first item (using [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/))

Comment: That totally works! Thank you :)

I am going to spend some time exploring $arrayElemAt and $filter. Thanks, again!